# PrestaShop: how to get the IDs of the select categories in a Category Treeview?

Tags: treeview, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm making a module in Prestashop 1.6 where the admin will be able to set quotas dive groups and categories. Tables below:

```
CREATE TABLE quota
(
    id_quota INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_group INT NOT NULL,
    max_amount_per_order INT NOT NULL,
    max_amount_per_month INT NOT NULL
);
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE quota_category
(
    id_quota_category BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_category INT NOT NULL,
    id_quota INT NOT NULL,
);
```

As you can see it is one record in the first table and many in de second.

Do to the form for this I use a select for the group and a treeview for the categories, all using the form help, I'm not using `.tpl` files.

```
            array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'label' => $this->l('Group'),
                'name' => 'id_group',
                'options' => array(
                    'query' => GroupCore::getGroups($this->context->language->id),
                    'id' => 'id_group',
                    'name' => 'name',
                ),
                'required' => true
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'categories',
                'label' => $this->l('Category'),
                'name' => 'id_category',
                'tree' => [
                    'selected_categories' => [1,2,4],
                    'disabled_categories' => null,
                    'use_search' => true,
                    'use_checkbox' => true,
                    'id' => 'id_category_tree',
                ],
                'required' => true
            ),
```

The form is rendering as intended, my problem is that I don't know now how I can treat the form to insert in both tables.

Can you give some help? I was trying to find similar cases but I couldn't find so far.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it. The `processSave()` is called on `add` and `update` and the object it returns always have the `id` property. When defining the treeview in the form you set a name to it. Just use Tool::getValue('name_of_the_treeview').

```
public function processSave() {

    $obj = parent::processSave();
    $categoryIds = Tools::getValue('id_categories');
    $id = $obj->id;

    Db::getInstance()->execute('delete from '._DB_PREFIX_.'adnquota_category where id_adnquota = '. pSQL($obj->id));

    if($categoryIds) {

        for($i = 0; $i < count($categoryIds); $i++){
            $rec = new AdnquotaCategoryModel();
            $rec->id_adnquota = $id;
            $rec->id_category = $categoryIds[$i];
            $rec->add();
        }
    }

    return $obj;
}
```